# Django-Auto-Complete Autocomplete not Registered error

Tags: django, django-forms, django-autocomplete-light

when I launch the runserver command on Django, I receive an error which looks like this:

```
autocomplete_light.exceptions.AutocompleteNotRegistered: CityAutocomplete not registered (registry is empty)
```

What puzzles me is that CityAutocomplete is registered and I checked this by going to `localhost:8000/autocomplete/CityAutocomplete`

Does anyone know what's wrong? 
Here is my
forms.py:

```
class OppForm(forms.ModelForm):
    opp_city = forms.ModelChoiceField(City.objects.all(), widget=autocomplete_light.ChoiceWidget('CityAutocomplete'))

class Meta:
    model = Opportunity
    fields = ('name','start', 'end', 'expiration','description','opp_type','location','street_address','opp_city', 'hours_per_week','opp_pic','extra_field_number','label1','label2','label3','label4','label5',)
    exclude = ('by_booth','opp_by')
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(OppForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['extra_field_number'].label = "Number of Extra Fields"
```

Here's my autocomplete_light_registry.py:

```
import autocomplete_light

from cities_light.models import City

class CityAutocomplete(autocomplete_light.AutocompleteModelBase):
    search_fields = ['^name', ]

autocomplete_light.register(City, CityAutocomplete)
```

My ultimate goal is to try to use django-cities-light and django-autocomplete to create a form field that allows users to type in a city to get autocomplete suggestions. 
Thanks again!

**Update:**
One possible problem I thought of is that it's possible that the widget cannot locate CityAutocomplete because of my project structure. My apps are all in a folder called apps in the project directory, instead of being located directly in the root of the project directory.

Comment: Are you calling `autocomplete_light.autodiscover()` in your urlconf, before `admin.autodiscover()`?

Comment: Yes, I followed the documentation. Not sure what's happening though.

Comment: As long as your `autocomplete_light_registry` is importable as `yourapp.autocomplete_light_registry`, it should work. Do you get a traceback with your error? If not, you can often run management commands with the `--traceback` option

Comment: Thank you very much, I managed to fix it by simply importing it manually.

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't seen this earlier. What's the name of your app ? TBH I copied django.contrib.admin's autodiscover() function so it should work the same.

Answer (score 3):

Did you also put `autocomplete_light.autodiscover()` in `forms.py`?

The documentation says:

> In urls.py, call autocomplete_light.autodiscover() before admin.autodiscover() **and before any import of a form with autocompletes**, it can look like this...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I figured it out, it turned out to be a problem with auto_complete being installed in the wrong directory, pip did something wrong!